# An identity found on oblate spheroidal wave functions. Is it possible to prove this result?

Tags: special-functions

For oblate spheroidal angular and radial functions as defined in Flammer's book: [Spheroidal Wave Functions](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=GjusAAAAIAAJ&dq=spheroidal+wave+functions&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR7r-P9OjXAhXLH5QKHWNhCqgQ6AEIJjAA). I found an identity by numerical simulations shown that

> $$
> \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty\left[\frac{S_{mn}(-ic,\pm 1)}{\sqrt{N_{mn}(-ic)}}R_{mn}^{(1)}(-ic,i\xi)\right]^2 = \frac12
> $$
>   for arbitrary $c$ and $\xi$.

Can anyone prove this result?

This identity may play an important role in some problems in physics concerning *laws of conservation of energy*.

**Edit #1**:

**More detail about the Flammer's definition can be found [HERE](http://www.mathieuandspheroidalwavefunctions.com/index.php?p=1_6_Oblate-Spheroidal-Functions)** (click *Click here for a description of oblfcn* at the bottom of the website).

The definition of $S_{mn}(-ic,\eta)$ reads that
$$
S_{mn}(-ic,\eta)=\sum_{r=0,1}^{\infty'} d_r^{mn}(-ic)P_{m+r}^m(\eta)
$$
where $P_{m+r}^m(\eta)$ is the associated Legendre function.
The $S_{mn}(-ic,\eta)$ form an orthogonal set on the interval $(-1,1)$, here the normaliation factor is
$$
N_{mn}(-ic)=2\sum_{r=0,1}^{\infty'}\frac{(r+2m)![d_r^{mn}(-ic)]^2}{(2r+2m+1)r!}
$$

The definition of $R_{mn}^{(1)}(-ic,i\xi)$ reads that
$$
R_{mn}^{(1)}(-ic,i\xi) = \left(\frac{\xi^2+1}{\xi^2}\right)^{m/2} \frac{\sum_{r=0,1}^{\infty'} i^{r+m-n} d_r^{mn}(-ic) j_{m+r}(c\xi) \frac{(r+2m)!}{r!}}{\sum_{r=0,1}^{\infty'} d_r^{mn}(-ic)\frac{(r+2m)!}{r!}}
$$
where $j_m(x)$ is the first kind of spherical Bessel function.

Comment: I'm always happy to see special functions problems, but this is missing a lot of details: How are $S_{mn}$, $R_{mn}$ defined? An obvious choice would be the DLMF, but its remarks in [section 30.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/30.1) on notation for spheroidal wavefunctions suggest that its notation is different than Flammer's.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for your concerns! You may check my last edit.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I am almost sure that you have worked on these very interesting functions (Prolate spheroidals). I don't know enough this subject ...

Comment: @Claude Leibovici One of the exceptional properties of prolate spheroidals is that they are orthogonal on two very different domains [-1,1] and $(-\infty,+\infty)$ simultaneously ; see §4 of (http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/74B/jresv74Bn3p187_A1b.pdf)